# How do I grab specific text from a string of changing length?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a string containing information that I would like to extract. My problem is that the string length can change based on product version, username, password, etc. Therefore I can't just say variable[155:185].  I think this my be a regex solution, but I have never worked with regex and am unsure.

I've tried using the variable[155:185] but this does not work due unless the string length is definite.

**_____This is the String I am Extracting from_____**

[('loginTapped() - Login in success. id: fakeemail@gmail.com - Password123',), ('loginTapped() - Login Button - version: 1.03.29 (29)',), ('logFoundBleNames() - Found bleNames: , VR0796a3',), ('viewDidLoad() - viewDidLoad',), ('waitTimerSerialNumEvent(timer:) - Found XY Appliance: VR0796a3 and serial:  macAddress: 0025ca0796a3',), ('wifiScanTimerEvent(timer:) - Wifi list requested. Name: VR0796a3',), ('refrigeratorTapped() - segue_to_enter_pin_sid',), ('viewDidLoad() - viewDidLoad',), ('applianceTapped() - segue_to_wifi_select_sid',), ('viewDidLoad() - viewDidLoad',), ('prepare(for:sender:) - segue_to_prod_wifi_setup_sid with: IotTest',), ('viewDidLoad() - Got a valid mac: 0025ca0796a3',), ('viewDidLoad() - viewDidLoad',), ('onRecordButton - wifi: IotTest',), ('addWifiNameToParamOut(wifi:) - Added WiFi name to apParamOut: IotTest',), ('setDevicePrivilegeCloud(macAddress:userApiKey:devicePin:privilegeCompletionHandler:) - Called with: mac: 0025ca0796a3 apiKey: 757d1040 devicePin: 1234',), ('setDevicePrivilegeCloud(macAddress:userApiKey:devicePin:privilegeCompletionHandler:) - \nDevice Apikey: c8b428e2\n',), ('setPassphrase(psswd:) - Enter setPassphrase with  appliance.apParamOut.count:  38 - psswd len: 9',), ('onRecordButton - Calling updateApplianceRecord() after Cloud call',), ('updateApplianceRecord() - updating appliance record: name: Optional("XY0796a3") mac: 0025ca0796a3 serial:  appl name: Optional("Freezer") modelID: 6',), ('setupChangeNotification() - Setup Complete (notification). Returning to the Product Select Screen now.',), ('setupChangeNotification() - Calling updateApplianceRecord() in Notification call',)]

```
import _sqlite3
# SQL to readable text

#add a time stamp!!
from Functions import create_connection

global Error
Error = False
try:
    UserFile = open("UserFriend.txt", "w")

except:
    UserFile = open("UserFriend.txt", "w+")

filename = "perfect_viking_connect.db"
perfect = "perfect_viking_connect.db"
#type1 = "Crash"
#type2 = "Connection Issue"

#cause1 = "Possible too far away"
#cause2 = "Poor connection with router with eiter phone or appliance"

def Friendly_Output(line):
    # Begin Searching
    ####################################################################################################
        #Login
        #######################################################
    if Error == False and "Login in success" in line:
        UserFile.write("User Information" + line)
    if Error == True and "Login in Success" in line:
        UserFile.write("There was a Login Error")
        # Version
        ########################################################
    if Error == False and "Login Button" in line:  # and if next line doesn't load then and Error has occured
        UserFile.write("\nUser is on Version: " + line[42:49])
    #else:
        #UserFile.write("\nAn error has occurred on login possible errors are")  # + type1,type2,type3,type4)
        # Found Bluetooth
        ########################################################
    if Error == False and "Found bleNames" in line:  # and if next line doesn't load then and Error has occured
        UserFile.write("\nSystem has found the Bluetooth name: " + line[41:49] +"\n")
    #else:
        #UserFile.write("\nAn error has occurred while searching for Appliances Bluetooth")

        # Request Wifi List
        ########################################################
    if Error == False and "Found VR" in line:  # and if next line doesn't load then and Error has occured
        UserFile.write("\n______Wifi information______\nVR Appliance: " + line[56:64] + "\n" + "Serial:\n" + "macAddress: " + line[90:102])
    #else:
        #UserFile.write("\nAn error has occurred receiving appliance information")  # + type1,type2,type3,type4)

        # Nic Board wifi request
        ########################################################
    if Error == False and "waitTimerSerialNumEvent" in line:  # and if next line doesn't load then and Error has occured
        UserFile.write("\n\nNIC is requesting wifi list")
    #else:
        #pass
        # Enter Pin Screen
        ########################################################
    if Error == False and "enter_pin_sid" in line:  # and if next line doesn't load then and Error has occured
        UserFile.write("\nUser is passed to enter pin screen")
    #else:
        #UserFile.write("\nAn error has occurred transferring to pin screen")  # + type1,type2,type3,type4)")
        # Wifi selection screen
        ########################################################
    if Error == False and "wifi_select_sid" in line: # and if next line doesn't load then and Error has occured
        UserFile.write(("\nUser is selecting wifi connection from list"))
    #else:
        #UserFile.write(("\nThere was an error")) # + type1, type2, type3
        # Wifi Setup Screen
        ########################################################
    if Error == False and "wifi_setup" in line: # and if next line doesn't load then and Error has occured
        UserFile.write("\nUser is on wifi credentials page")
    #else:
        #UserFile.write("\nAn error has occurred while searching for appliances\n")  # + type1,type2,type3,type4)

        # User has pressed enter
        ########################################################
    if Error == False and " - wifi: " in line:  # and if next line doesn't load then and Error has occured
        UserFile.write("\nUser has entered credentials and pressed enter")
    #else:
        #UserFile.write("\nAn error has occurred while starting the cloud setup process\n")  # + type1,type2,type3,type4)

        # Adding pass/fail
        ########################################################
    if Error == False and "addWifiNameTo" in line:
        UserFile.write("\nUser has successfully added their connection")
    #else:
        #UserFile.write("\nThe wifi addition process has failed")

    '''     # Pinging cloud to add new information
        ########################################################
    if Error == False and "addWifiNameTo" in line:
        UserFile.write("\nUser has successfully added their connection")
    #else:
        #UserFile.write("\nThe wifi addition process has failed")'''
        ########################################################


        #Beginning Cloud talk
        ##########################################################################
    if Error == False and "Called with: mac:" in line:
        UserFile.write("\n\n____Cloud Talk has Begun____\nMac address: " + line[107:119] + "\nApikey: " + line[128:136] + "\nDevice Pin: " + line[148:152])
    if Error == True and "Called with: mac:"  in line:
        print("Cloud Talk Failed")
        #Device Apikey
        ########################################################
    if Error == False and r"\nDevice Apikey:" in line:
        UserFile.write("\nDevice Apikey: " + line[106:114])
    if Error == True and r"\nDevice Apikey:" in line:
        pass
####################################################################################################
def nextrowfinder(Current_Row):
    if "Login in success. id:" in Current_Row:
        KnowNextRow = "loginTapped() - Login Button - version:"
        return KnowNextRow
    elif "loginTapped() - Login Button - version:" in Current_Row:
        KnowNextRow = "logFoundBleNames() - Found bleNames:"
        return KnowNextRow
    elif "logFoundBleNames() - Found bleNames:" in Current_Row:
        KnowNextRow = "viewDidLoad() - viewDidLoad"
        return KnowNextRow
   # elif "viewDidLoad() - viewDidLoad" in Current_Row:
    #    KnowNextRow = "waitTimerSerialNumEvent(timer:) - Found VR Appliance:"
    #    return KnowNextRow
    elif "waitTimerSerialNumEvent(timer:) - Found VR Appliance:" in Current_Row:
        KnowNextRow = "wifiScanTimerEvent(timer:) - Wifi list requested. Name:"
        return KnowNextRow
    elif "wifiScanTimerEvent(timer:) - Wifi list requested. Name:" in Current_Row:
        KnowNextRow = "refrigeratorTapped() - segue_to_enter_pin_sid"
        return KnowNextRow
    elif "refrigeratorTapped() - segue_to_enter_pin_sid" in Current_Row:
        KnowNextRow = "viewDidLoad() - viewDidLoad"
        return KnowNextRow
    #elif "viewDidLoad() - viewDidLoad" in Current_Row:
     #   KnowNextRow = "applianceTapped() - segue_to_wifi_select_sid"
      #  return KnowNextRow
    elif "applianceTapped() - segue_to_wifi_select_sid" in Current_Row:
        KnowNextRow = "viewDidLoad() - viewDidLoad"
        return KnowNextRow
    #elif "viewDidLoad() - viewDidLoad" in Current_Row:
    #    KnowNextRow = "prepare(for:sender:) - segue_to_prod_wifi_setup_sid with:"
    #    return KnowNextRow
    elif "prepare(for:sender:) - segue_to_prod_wifi_setup_sid with:" in Current_Row:
        KnowNextRow = "viewDidLoad() - Got a valid mac:"
        return KnowNextRow
    elif "viewDidLoad() - Got a valid mac:" in Current_Row:
        KnowNextRow = "viewDidLoad() - viewDidLoad"
        return KnowNextRow
    #elif "viewDidLoad() - viewDidLoad" in Current_Row:
    #    KnowNextRow = "onRecordButton - wifi:"
    #    return KnowNextRow
    elif "onRecordButton - wifi:" in Current_Row:
        KnowNextRow = "addWifiNameToParamOut(wifi:) - Added WiFi name to apParamOut:"
        return KnowNextRow
    elif "addWifiNameToParamOut(wifi:) - Added WiFi name to apParamOut:" in Current_Row:
        KnowNextRow = "setDevicePrivilegeCloud(macAddress:userApiKey:devicePin:privilegeCompletionHandler:) - Called with: mac:"
        return KnowNextRow
    elif "setDevicePrivilegeCloud(macAddress:userApiKey:devicePin:privilegeCompletionHandler:) - Called with: mac:" in Current_Row:
        KnowNextRow = "setDevicePrivilegeCloud(macAddress:userApiKey:devicePin:privilegeCompletionHandler:) - \nDevice Apikey:"
        return KnowNextRow
    elif "setDevicePrivilegeCloud(macAddress:userApiKey:devicePin:privilegeCompletionHandler:) - \nDevice Apikey:" in Current_Row:
        KnowNextRow = "setPassphrase(psswd:) - Enter setPassphrase with  appliance.apParamOut.count:"
        return KnowNextRow
    elif "setPassphrase(psswd:) - Enter setPassphrase with  appliance.apParamOut.count:" in Current_Row:
        KnowNextRow = "onRecordButton - Calling updateApplianceRecord() after Cloud call"
        return KnowNextRow
    elif "onRecordButton - Calling updateApplianceRecord() after Cloud call" in Current_Row:
        KnowNextRow = "updateApplianceRecord() - updating appliance record: name: Optional"
        return KnowNextRow
    elif "updateApplianceRecord() - updating appliance record: name: Optional" in Current_Row:
        KnowNextRow = "setupChangeNotification() - Setup Complete (notification). Returning to the Product Select Screen now."
        return KnowNextRow
    elif "setupChangeNotification() - Setup Complete (notification). Returning to the Product Select Screen now." in Current_Row:
        KnowNextRow = "setupChangeNotification() - Calling updateApplianceRecord() in Notification call"
        return KnowNextRow
    elif "setupChangeNotification() - Calling updateApplianceRecord() in Notification call" in Current_Row:
        KnowNextRow = "End of Setup Log\n\n\n"
        return KnowNextRow
    elif "viewDidLoad() - viewDidLoad" in Current_Row:
        KnowNextRow = "View Load"
        return KnowNextRow
    else:
        KnowNextRow = "Error"
        return KnowNextRow
####################################################################################################




def main():
    list = create_connection(filename)  # create_connection(database)
    global Error
    #counter = 0
    cur = list.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT error_text from error_log ")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    perlist = create_connection(perfect)
    percur = perlist.cursor()
    percur.execute("SELECT error_text from error_log Where id >= 2")
    perrows = percur.fetchall()

    #for row in rows:
    #   counter = counter + 1

    #for count in range(counter):

    rows_list = []
    perrows_list = []

    for row in rows:
        KnowNextRow = nextrowfinder(str(row))
        rows_list.append(KnowNextRow)

    for perrow in perrows:
        PerfectNextRow = perrow
        xx = (str(PerfectNextRow))
        perrows_list.append(xx)
    rows_len = len(rows_list)  # Get length of lists to ensure they are the same
    perlen = len(perrows_list)

    #print(rows_list)
    #print(perrows_list)

    for idx, Know_Next in enumerate(rows_list):
        if idx < (perlen - 1):  # Check that perrows item exists
            if Know_Next in perrows_list[idx]:
                #print("Match on line " + str(idx))
                pass

            else:
                print("View Did Load Screen")




main()
```

I I want to pull model number i've try variable[start:end], but I will only get it if the user places an exact string length. I would like to do some sort of search for the keyword and grab the text following it.

Comment: What text are you trying to extract from your given text? Can you share your python code that you attempted?

Comment: The text is extracted from a SQL .db file. I'll upload the python code. At the moment I'm trying to extract Username and Password, model number, serial number, mac address, and WiFi list name, and appl name.

Comment: Um, where did this text get created? It looks like someone printed out a list of tuples to a text file. Is that what happened? Because if so, the you should really solve *that*.

Comment: Wait, why are you converting what the db returns to a string? `str(row)`?

Comment: @ZackGarris: Can you list the expected data of model number, serial number, wifi listname and appl name? This isn't clear from your given data.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was receiving a type error before conversion.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi What do you mean by expected data?

Comment: @ZackGarris That doesn't really answer anything. Why are you processing a list of tuples as a *string* representation of a list of tuples?

Comment: Expected data means what all actual data you wanted. Like in your given text I couldn't find what data you wanted for serial name or wifi name or model name in your given data

Comment: Your regex solution below actually grabbed the expected data, and I do believe I can use this to grab anything else I may need from the string. The wifi name was IotTest. I'm going to try to add apikey and device pin. The serial number has not been added to the string yet.Thank You for the help!

Comment: Read it by pointer. Maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could only find these five information in your given text, which are username, password, modelnumber, macaddress and applname. I've constructed a named groups regex so it is easy for you to grasp the content. The regex to be used is,

```
(?s)id: (?P<username>.+?) - (?P<password>.+?)'.*Appliance: (?P<modelnumber>\S+).*macAddress: (?P<macaddress>.+?)'.*appl name: (?P<applname>\S+)
```

Here `(?s)` is for enabling `.` to match newlines as well as your data seems to span across multiple lines. And rest named groups are in order of appearance of data. If you need to find more information from your text, you can enhance the regex to capture more information in a similar way or call me for help in case you find it hard.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0DSw1v/1)**

Sample Python codes,

```
import re

s = '''[('loginTapped() - Login in success. id: fakeemail@gmail.com - Password123',), ('loginTapped() - Login Button - version: 1.03.29 (29)',), ('logFoundBleNames() - Found bleNames: , VR0796a3',), ('viewDidLoad() - viewDidLoad',), ('waitTimerSerialNumEvent(timer:) - Found XY Appliance: VR0796a3 and serial: macAddress: 0025ca0796a3',), ('wifiScanTimerEvent(timer:) - Wifi list requested. Name: VR0796a3',), ('refrigeratorTapped() - segue_to_enter_pin_sid',), ('viewDidLoad() - viewDidLoad',), ('applianceTapped() - segue_to_wifi_select_sid',), ('viewDidLoad() - viewDidLoad',), ('prepare(for:sender:) - segue_to_prod_wifi_setup_sid with: IotTest',), ('viewDidLoad() - Got a valid mac: 0025ca0796a3',), ('viewDidLoad() - viewDidLoad',), ('onRecordButton - wifi: IotTest',), ('addWifiNameToParamOut(wifi:) - Added WiFi name to apParamOut: IotTest',), ('setDevicePrivilegeCloud(macAddress:userApiKey:devicePin:privilegeCompletionHandler:) - Called with: mac: 0025ca0796a3 apiKey: 757d1040 devicePin: 1234',), ('setDevicePrivilegeCloud(macAddress:userApiKey:devicePin:privilegeCompletionHandler:) - \nDevice Apikey: c8b428e2\n',), ('setPassphrase(psswd:) - Enter setPassphrase with appliance.apParamOut.count: 38 - psswd len: 9',), ('onRecordButton - Calling updateApplianceRecord() after Cloud call',), ('updateApplianceRecord() - updating appliance record: name: Optional("XY0796a3") mac: 0025ca0796a3 serial: appl name: Optional("Freezer") modelID: 6',), ('setupChangeNotification() - Setup Complete (notification). Returning to the Product Select Screen now.',), ('setupChangeNotification() - Calling updateApplianceRecord() in Notification call',)]'''

m = re.search(r"(?s)id: (?P<username>.+?) - (?P<password>.+?)'.*Appliance: (?P<modelnumber>\S+).*macAddress: (?P<macaddress>.+?)'.*appl name: (?P<applname>\S+)", s)
if (m):
 print('username: {}, password: {}, modelnumber: {}, macaddress: {}, applname: {}'.format(m.group('username'),m.group('password'),m.group('modelnumber'),m.group('macaddress'),m.group('applname')))
```

Prints the information you request,

```
username: fakeemail@gmail.com, password: Password123, modelnumber: VR0796a3, macaddress: 0025ca0796a3, applname: Optional("Freezer")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import re
m = re.search(r'Found XY Appliance:\s*([^,]*)', dblogstring)
m.group(0)
```

It matches the text in brackets () which is anything that is not a comma.  It will reliably extract portions of a complicated string that changes dynamically.

Comment: I'm getting a NoneType error here. 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'.

Comment: As he's trying to extract username and password, what if the username or password contains `,`?

Comment: Regular expressions are really useful.  They are a little difficult.  Take the time to learn them, and this problem becomes a simple one.